# Burninate [opinion], please

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Today, a user contested the closure of his question with [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315452/using-superlatives-as-prefixes-order-of-significance#comment715942_315452):

> And yet there are opinion based questions all over this site. **There is even an 'opinion' tag** already.

And he's right, [there is](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion). There are currently seven questions so tagged, mostly run-of-the-mill and non-descript, and none but would be improved by the removal of the tag.

Let's burninate [opinion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion), please (meaning: remove and blacklist it). We don't need to arm future OPs with further excuses.

Comment: I suppose you could go though all six posts and retag them. I have done quite enough spring cleaning in the last two days and I'm pretty sure users are grumbling about the validity of my edits but are too polite to say so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have no problem removing the tag from the posts, it'll take two minutes (someone already did so for the seventh, and highest-voted question, which now no longer has the [opinion] tag). But I do want the tag "burninated", which is to say blacklisted, so it cannot be recreated. A secondary benefit of that approach is the affected questions won't float up to the top of the front page and bother people. I'm kinda waiting for a mod to weigh in one way or another on that decision.

Comment: Oh, a burninated tag cannot be recreated? I didn't know that. Hmmm... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag only "some" tags are blacklisted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just went through and removed the [tag:opinion] tag from all questions, along with [tag:perspective] and [tag:view] which has been created by the same question which introduced [opinion]. I don't have the power to blacklist these tags, and a quick check of MSE suggests that only developers might (as opposed to mods and even CMs), so I'm satisfied for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been burninated a while ago apparently. Please accept this CW to mark it done.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I removed it after asking the meta question, because it didn't seem like it would disrupt much, and a user was trying to use it to support his argument that he should be allowed to ask subjective questions on the site.