# Should we burninate the [subjective] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While doing some reviews, I was made aware of the existence of the [subjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) tag.  Given that we are a Q&A site which focuses explicitly on answering questions as objectively as possible and discourages subjectivity, this seems like a tag that should go the way of the [opinion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion) tag that was [recently removed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/burninate-opinion-please).

Admittedly, our [don't-ask page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) does allow that some subjective questions are permissible, but I don't see how tagging a question as subjective actually helps except to mark it for probable death.

In addition, of the mere 10 questions tagged [subjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective), at least 3 should probably be [nominative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nominative) instead (except we don't have a tag for that at the moment...); the questions that are really asking for a subjective opinion are at least 2 1/2 years old.

question list:
[What would I call an instance that handles animations; Animator or Animater?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370376/what-would-i-call-an-instance-that-handles-animations-animator-or-animater)

["Him" vs. "His" in a gerund subject phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328413/him-vs-his-in-an-subjective-phrase)

[preposition + genitive vs non-genitive subjects + gerund](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327887/preposition-genitive-vs-non-genitive-subjects-gerund)

[What is the difference between "He seemed to be angry." and "He seemed angry."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102028/what-is-the-difference-between-he-seemed-to-be-angry-and-he-seemed-angry)

[How common is "thrice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/how-common-is-thrice)

[Does "hopelessly lost" sound awkward?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154368/does-hopelessly-lost-sound-awkward)

[Word for "held up well over time"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85603/word-for-held-up-well-over-time)

[What are comparative strong points of online dictionaries and other useful reference sites?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32363/what-are-comparative-strong-points-of-online-dictionaries-and-other-useful-refer)

[What are some good books on articulation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/976/what-are-some-good-books-on-articulation)

[What is the most eloquent way to transition into pointing out a major flaw in someone's thinking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/what-is-the-most-eloquent-way-to-transition-into-pointing-out-a-major-flaw-in-so)

Comment: Please someone, for maximum irony, tag this meta question with subjective.

Comment: Or turn it into a tag for the grammatical term :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering because, from my experience on the [opinion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion) question, no one feels they have the authority to do more than vote.

So go ahead and remove all the [subjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) tags from those questions.

Sadly, I not believe it's in our power to blacklist the re-creation of the tag. We'd need a StackExchange employee to do that (not even an CM; I believe a developer has to do it).